# How to remove multiple email IDs from an account and only keep one

Tags: support, login, accounts

I have two email IDs for the same account on Stack Overflow. I am getting logged in with either of the email ids now. Even if I am trying to create another profile with the email id which I want to keep, it’s reverting me to the same profile.
I want to remove one of them completely and only want to keep one for this profile.
How should I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete one of your accounts?

Comment: @Larnu: I think he's got two login methods registered to _one_ account, and wants to unlink one login method do he can create another account...

Comment: @Larnu Roght now I have two login methods but I want to keep just one so I can use the second email ID for creating another account

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes exactly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me (`me` is a generic userId parameter :D)

Answer (score 4):

Go to your My Logins Page; `https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/{UserID}`, so for you that would be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/8721934). Alternatively you can use https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me. There you'll see your authentication methods. Click the Remove Button  for the one you want to remove.

[image]

Comment: I tried doing that but nothing is happening even if I click on it. There are two options. One for change password and other for remove. I am able to change the password but not remove.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to test removing an account, because I don't want to remove either of them, @N97 , so I can't try to replicate your problem.

Comment: @N97 Seems more users have this problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369949/cannot-delete-a-login

Comment: @N97 Rumor has it that the bug is fixed  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370101/237989

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes its fixed now. Finally removed one email id. Thanks!!